# Red Gate Profiler equivalent for Objective-C Mac / iPhone

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, profiler, red-gate-ants

I love the profiling tools that Red Gate makes for when I write in C#.  Right now I am writing an application for iPhone in Objective-C and I am having a hard time adjusting to Instruments.  It's just not as easy to use.  Does anybody have a better code profiler for memory and performance?  If not, any good tutorials for instruments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with Shark profiler, which is built-into xcode? It's a pretty decent tool. Might take a bit to adjust to it, but give it a try.

[Here's the basic introduction.](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html)

[Here's another.](http://developer.apple.com/tools/shark_optimize.html)

Answer (score 1):

Shark rocks.  You'll be hard pressed to find a better profiler.